# index on two columns that uniquely find a row

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Hi if I have tables like:

table_A:

```
time_id   |  transaction_id   |  other columns...
```

table_B:

```
time_id   |  transaction_id   |  other columns...
```

Combination of `time_id` and `transaction_id` uniquely defines a row (or almost uniquely)

The query I want to be fast is like:

```
SELECT ..
FROM [table_A] as a
join [table_B] as b 
   on a.time_id = b.time_id and a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id 
WHERE a.time_id = '201601' and b.time_id = '201601'
```

What would be the suggested practice in indexing?

I was thinking of

```
create index time_trans on [product] (time_id, transaction_id)
```

but is it too granular? (since combination of `time_id` and `transaction_id` uniquely defines a row)

---

how the tables were created (by loading csv into sql server, updated csv provided monthly)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_A] (
    [time_id] ...,
    [transaction_id] ...,
    [other columns] ...   
)

BULK INSERT [dbo].[table_A_2010]  
FROM 'table_A_2010.CSV'  
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )

BULK INSERT [dbo].[table_A_2011]  
FROM 'table_A_2011.CSV'  
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )

BULK INSERT [dbo].[table_A_2012]  
FROM 'table_A_2012.CSV'  
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )

...
```

Comment: Which table contains more records?

Comment: thank you @Shivam - similarly big: 600M rows and 700M rows.

Comment: Create unique constraint on those two columns and check it may help

Comment: Can you please post your CREATE TABLE statements for the two tables in your query?

Comment: I sure wouldn't bother with both predicates in your where clause. You know they have the same value for time_id because that is part of the join. Hopefully the optimizer is smart enough to ignore the redundant predicate.

Comment: And when you say uniquely identifies a row does that mean it is the composite primary key? Is it clustered? Without table and index definitions this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks - currently there's no primary key

Comment: @user1443098 thanks - see OP

Comment: Are you saying these tables have no indexes and no key? There is the problem. You have created heaps with a few hundred million rows each.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah - i'm more focused on machine learning and not very familiar with db performance tricks. Need to pick up

Comment: Not sure what that means really. But you need a primary key on your table. If there is no clustered index on the table the primary key will be your clustered index by default. Indexing is partially technical knowledge and a large part art. You learn that art from practice and lots of reading. Here is an amazing series of article on indexing. Starts basic and goes really deep as the articles progress. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177656/discussion-between-y-zhang-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 0):

For any new table, determine what column(s) uniquely identify a row then make that the PRIMARY KEY, which is automatically backed by an index (by default, a clustered index).

Answer (score 0):

Index on granular rows are good, in fact it's usually what you want.

Imagine you have a table that has a row for every human in the world. Which index do you think it would be better from these?

- Index by `sex` (male / female).
- Index by `name, surname`.
- Index by `bornCountry, documentNumber`.

There is no "better" index here. Reasons to compare indexes vary from case to case and at some point even what seems to be a lousy index will work better for certain scenarios.

For you case, creating an index by `time_id, transaction_id` seems a very sound choice, since you are filtering by `time_id` and joining against other table with `transaction_id`. Another case would be if you **don't** filter by `time_id`, might want to switch the order of the columns.

If you know that the combination of `time_id, transaction_id` is unique and has to be enforced you can create a `UNIQUE` index or if you don't have a clustered index yet, you can create a `CLUSTERED INDEX` which will reorganize the actual stored data to match this order which will make `SELECT` queries faster (but might hinder `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, depending on the inserted or updated values!).

If this combination can be repeated, you can simply create a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX`. It will help if you create the same index on the other table.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX time_trans on [product] (time_id, transaction_id)
```

Also keep in mind that you can `INCLUDE` columns on nonclustered indexes. You don't show which columns you actually `SELECT`, but consider including them on the index with `INCLUDE` so the engine doesn't have to read an additional page from disk when retriving the data since included columns on index store their value with the indexed columns.